# form 2 button + javascript issue

Tags: php, javascript, html

```
<form action="index.php?page=checkin" method="post" name="regForm">
    <div id="First_1">
        <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding: 5px;">
                                Fullständiga namn:
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input name="full_name" type="text" id="full_name" class="required">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding: 5px;">
                                Email:
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input name="usr_email" type="text" id="usr_email3" class="required">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding: 5px;">
                                Sex:
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <select name="sex">
                                    <option value="male">
                                        Kille
                                    </option>
                                    <option value="female">
                                        Tjej
                                    </option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="submit" id="continue" value="Fortsätt">
                        </td>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="Next_2" style="display: none">
        <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding: 5px;">
                                Lösenord:
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input name="pwd" type="password" class="required password" id="pwd">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                En gång till..
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input name="pwd2" id="pwd2" class="required password" type="password">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input name="doRegister" type="submit" id="doRegister" value="Register">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#continue").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "dbc.php",
                data: {
                    check: 'First',
                    full_name: $('#full_name').val(),
                    usr_email: $('#usr_email3').val()
                },
                success: function(msg) {
                    if (msg == '1') {
                        $("#First_1").hide();
                        $("#Next_2").toggle();
                    } else {
                        alert(msg);
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thats my form. You fill 3 form elements to start with, then you press the Continue button, and then it sends ajax call to check the fields. If everythings OK (if output = 1 from ajax call), Next_2 gets toggled on, where you enter your password twice. After that you press on the final button Register, which should do "action=index.php?page=checkin", but it doesnt, when i press register it just get blank, and i can see in firebug that it sends another ajax call which i cannot understand because the button doesnt have id="continue" but id="doRegister"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the "Continue" button doesn't actually submit the form, try declaring it as a normal button instead of a submit button, like this:

```
<input type="button" id="continue" value="Fortsätt">
```

I'm guessing that having two submit buttons on the same form is somehow causing interactions with the handler.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make the "Continue" button as type="button" and not submit

```
<input type="button" id="continue" value="Fortsätt">
```